# Cover Background Image Isn't Correct On Some Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, background-image

I have a site that uses a background with a size of "cover" for the top of the page. The image is supposed to change based on the resolution of the screen, but certain devices show the image from the desktop or tablet version. The website is [rookmgmt.ca](http://rookmgmt.ca), and I'll include the relevant HTML and CSS code.

Edit: To be more specific, the image is far too large on some devices. Instead of the city skyline, it shows only the top part of the sky. It works on my phone and others that I've tested personally, but not on every device.

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-background bg-1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>ROOK PROPERTY<br>
                        MANAGEMENT INC.</h1>
                    <h2>CONDOMINIUM MANAGEMENT</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed-background {
    height: 800px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-background.bg-1 {
    background-image: url("../images/IMG_6642-2_mobile.jpg");
}
```

Meta Tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px)" href="css/styles_mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px)" href="css/styles_tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1200px)" href="css/styles_desk.css">
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but removing the min-width from the meta tags worked for me.

Comment: I'll give it a try. The problem I'm having is that the image is far larger than it should be on the screen, only showing the top part of the image. It doesn't seem to be on every device (it works on my phone), but it seems to be the case on some apple devices.

Answer (score 0):

**use percentage instead different pixel description**

```css
.fixed-background {
    height: 50%;
    width: 30%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-background.bg-1 {
    background-image: url("../images/IMG_6642-2_mobile.jpg");
}
```

Comment: This does nothing other than make the div smaller